# How to set appropriate height for a baby saucer?

Tags: infant, play-time, growth, walking

I want to make sure that I do not set it too high or too low.

If it sets too high a baby can have a bad walking habit because he walks on his toe. But if it's too low, it can cause his legs support too much of his weight. That's what I heard. Now, I set it on second step from three adjustable steps.

[image: Now, I set it on second step from three adjustable steps.]

Comment: Please check out [this question about walkers and saucers](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/are-exersaucers-walkers-jumpers-bad-for-children-or-is-that-simply-a-misconcepti), in general children learn walking best on their own.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer's information should have instructions, but based on what I remember from ours, if you set it so his knees are slightly bent when he sits down in it and the seat part no longer supports him if he stands up, it should be good (photo looks like you've got it right).  I've also heard (from my sis whose baby just turned one) the toe thing is less of a concern than they thought a few years ago too.